# Memory allocation of a program

Tags: memory, operating-system

i try to understand how the memory allocation of programs work in detail and i am aware of the concepts heap, stack etc.

After searching a visualization of a "simple" allocation i saw 2 types:

1. The stack is on the higher address:

[image]

2. The heap is on the higher address:

[image]

**I have 2 questions here:**

1. Which one of this right or is this depending on the os?
2. If the example 1 is right => what happens if the heap is too big and would grow in the stack?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the OS. In general though, the stack is allocated with a fixed size and doesn't grow past it. Programmers attempt to avoid allocating a lot of data using automatic storage (local variables) to avoid the stack getting full. They will use the heap for big data chunks instead.

On x64, 48 bits paging with 4 page table levels is used. This allows around 262 thousand GB of virtual address space (VAS). Every process has its own base pointer for page tables (the CR3 register). Their instructions can access any byte in that huge VAS as long as the address range they access is backed by physical memory (or as long as every process is not using all memory available at once including swap space). The kernel reserves the top half of the VAS since no process in existence will ever need as much as even half of it.

Since each process can allocate any region of the bottom half of the VAS, the heap can grow indefinitely without reaching the stack. If the heap reaches the stack, it means you allocated more than 100k GB to your process which is not possible unless you are Google, Amazon or others.

The heap is allocated while the process runs with a system call. The process puts the memory allocation syscall number in a register defined by the OS as the right register to pass the syscall number. With Linux, it is standardized by the System V standard. After this, the process executes the [syscall](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall) instruction making the processor jump in the kernel at the address stored at boot by the kernel in the IA32_LSTAR register. It allows securely jumping to the kernel without giving full access to the kernel.

When the syscall returns, the address in the VAS of the allocated memory chunk is found in the return register which is also standardized. From there the process can assume that this register contains the address of the allocated memory or an error code (the compiler generates instructions operating on that register).

For the stack, the size of every allocation is already known when the program is compiled. The compiler generates prologues and epilogues for every function you call. Without optimization and with a frame pointer, the prologue is something like:

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, SOME_AMOUNT_OF_MEMORY
```

Basically, current RBP is saved, current RSP is saved in RBP and RSP is subtracted of the amount of memory required for the function. In the epilogue, the contrary operations are done to come back to the previous state of the stack. It is the sub rsp part that allocates stack memory. From there, the instructions that constitute the body of the function (between prologue and epilogue) access local variables with a relative negative offset from RBP:

```
mov [RBP - some_offset], some_number_or_register
```

This is why local variables have to be initialized after being declared or initialized at declaration because otherwise their content might just be random garbage left there by the previous function. It might even be another process since there is no specific requirement to zero out pages that make up the stack (even though it might be done). This is because, in the epilogue of each function, RSP is simply incremented and everything is left there.

Since the initial value of RSP is choosen by the OS, the stack can be anywhere and still work because the data access is relative and has to be initialized explicitly. The heap also has to be initialized explicitly for similar reasons but random data wasn't left there by the previous function and it might be zeroed out.

For static/global data (everything declared static or outside a function), the data is in the executable's data segment and simply copied in RAM before execution at a fixed offset from the code segment. This data is accessed using an offset from the program counter (RIP on x64):

```
mov [RIP +/- some_offset], something
or
mov register, [RIP +/- some_offset]
```

This allows the code to be position independent since every data access is relative to something for every instructions generated before program execution. For the heap, it isn't necessary since it is dynamically allocated. This allows to randomly choose a starting address for your executable even after compilation for security purposes (called ASLR).